# Unable to locate package - troubleshooting tips

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running into an issue where I'm getting package not found on an Indigo install. It looks like there are a lot of questions about specific packages in the forum and I was wondering if there are general troubleshooting steps that should be taken to 1) determine if the packages are in fact in storage but not installed or 2) not installed at all.  If apt-get isn't finding the package, I"m thinking that the location for packages in my configuration that's missing. Could that be the case?  I ran roslocate for the rviz package (see below) and it came back with a 404 error.  Are there other tools that I should be using to determine if this is the issue?

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ros-tutorials ros-indigo-geometry-tutorials ros-indigo-rviz ros-indigo-rosbash ros-indigo-rqt-tf-tree
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-ros-tutorials
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-geometry-tutorials
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-rviz
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-rosbash
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-rqt-tf-tree

roslocate info ros-indigo-rviz
Using ROS_DISTRO: indigo
Not found via rosdistro - falling back to information provided by rosdoc
error contacting http://ros.org/doc/indigo/api/ros-indigo-rviz/stack.yaml:
HTTP Error 404: Not Found
error contacting http://ros.org/doc/indigo/api/ros-indigo-rviz/manifest.yaml:
HTTP Error 404: Not Found
cannot locate information about ros-indigo-rviz
```

---

Edit:

> Try sudo apt-get update and then the install

That command allowed the packages to be located. However, after locating the packages and trying to install again, I'm getting the message below.  I'll post that to a different question so it's not lost.

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214656/unable-to-locate-package---troubleshooting-tips/) by [d7x](https://answers.ros.org/users/23168/d7x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2015-07-27

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-28**:
Please do not use *Answers* as forum posts, or to post *comments*, use the 'add comment' button for that. Updates to your original question should be added using an 'edit' to your OP. I've moved the contents to your OP this time, but please keep it in mind.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-28**:
Also: please add -- to all questions -- which OS this is, version of the OS, processor architecture, version of ROS and how you installed it: from source or using the debians (that is somewhat clear here already, obviously). Especially architectures *other than* x86/x64 can have pkgs missing fi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try sudo apt-get update
and then the install

Try First

- sudo apt-get remove ros-indigo-ros-tutorials ros-indigo-geometry-tutorials ros-indigo-rviz ros-indigo-rosbash ros-indigo-rqt-tf-tree
- sudo apt-get install
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ros-base
- sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ros-tutorials
- sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-geometry-tutorials
- sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rviz
- sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rosbash
- sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-rqt-tf-tree

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2015-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nithin73](https://answers.ros.org/users/26533/nithin73/) on 2016-04-21**:
After executing these I get the same error stating that "unable to locate the package ros-indigo-ros-base.Can you help me